# How to execute a cron job every 1 hour infinitely starting from particular time?

Tags: linux, cron, at-command

I wanted to execute the cron job indefinitely for every 1 minute starting at immediate occurrence of 6:30 AM  using the following pattern :

`30/1 6 * * *`

But cron stops at 6:59 AM and never executes thereafter.

Should I make the pattern as `30/1 6-0 * * *`. But I am afraid that the cron may not be invoked after first occurance of 12 AM.

So, will the following pattern resolve the issue?
`30/1 6-* * * *`

Comment: You can't have a `cron` that will run at X time and every 1 minute indefinitely. For the former condition, you need to use command like `at` to put the cron file in place during that time.

Comment: What is such a frequent `cron` job *actually* doing? Looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), because probably there are better ways to solve your needs. So please, **edit your question** to motivate it  and explain what your program is *really* doing every minute

Answer (score 2):

This runs a cron every 1 minute. For such a high frequency cron job, one should carefully figure out race conditions.

```
 $ cat ./my1min-cron
 */1 * * * * root /path/to/some/script &> /path/to/some/log

 $ chmod 644 ./my1min-cron
```

Use `at` to place it at the next 6:30 AM. For example,

```
 # Create a script that will copy the cron file to /etc/cron.d/
 $ cat ./putcronscript.sh
 cp -vf ./my1min-cron /etc/cron.d/my1min-cron &> ./copycronscript.log

 # Use at to put the cron script in place at 6:30 AM Tuesday. This is onetime operation.
 $ at -f ./putcronscript.sh 6:30 AM Tue

 # or
 $ at -f ./putcronscript.sh 6:30 AM tomorrow
```